# How to simulate different server responses, including offline?

Tags: java, android, networking

An app I am working on relies on connecting to a private, remote server to login via an API.

The other day, I got an ANR message and I think it was due to the server being offline (its a Windows Server that was being updated).

In my app, I am using the following code:

```
new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute(url).get();
```

Which turns an AsyncTask into a synchronous task (I believe!)

And because the server was offline, I think the app got hung up, causing the ANR (it's my only lead at the moment, and all seems to make sense, despite the code above is inside a Service class, which shouldn't cause an ANR, should it?)

So, I want to try an simulate the server being offline. I tried replacing the URL with one that simply doesn't work, by removing some letters from the hostname, but that only triggered an "UnknownHostException".

Is there any way to achieve this kind of simulation? I know there are tools for browsers to simulate low bandwidth etc, but have no idea what could be done when my app is running on Android and is trying to connect to a remote server that I can't really reboot at will.

Comment: `Which turns an AsyncTask into a synchronous task (I believe)`. It's scary so many people things that it's fine to use tools they do not understand. Hope you not going to work on medical software or so

Comment: The concept which you should familiarize yourself is "[mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)". You can mock your server response, and test for every possible response this way. A good tutorial about mocking can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EasyMock/article.html).

Comment: Yes, `get()` on `AsyncTask` blocks until the asynctask finishes. Service code runs on the main thread as well. If you block the main thread for 5 seconds or more, you get ANR.

Comment: Marcin - your comment is not helpful. I know what the code does, I'm just not 100% on the terms for it.

Comment: laalto - Can I simply use the version of get() where I add the timeout? If I set that to time out before 5 seconds, that should stop any ANR's right?